# Obtain input and output of Java program through bash

Tags: java, bash

I have a java Program which accepts inputs and prints outputs based on the input provided by the user. For example, when I run it, the program prompts the user:

```
System Starts  

login <--- User input

Login Successful
```

I want to be able to run the program through bash and save the output of the program to a text file.

This is what I tried:

```
echo "login" | javac TicketSystem/src/*.java > Output.txt
```

But when I do this, my `Output.txt` file remains empty. I want the `Output.txt` file to contain:

```
Login Successful
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you see "Login Successful" on the screen when you run that? And is `javac` how you run it when it prompts you for login normally?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not actually sure if I'm supposed to use `javac` or not, I thought that's what I need to do to run the java program. When I run the program using javac however, I don't see anything on the screen, that is only what is shown in Eclipse

Comment: That's because `javac` is a java compiler not a java runner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a java program, you must use `java` and specify the name of the class containing your `main` method.

Before you can run it, you must ofcourse first compile the `.java` source file into a `.class` file.

For instance you have `Foo.java` containing a `public static void main(String[] args)`.

1. compile it:  `javac Foo.java`  --> this gives you a `Foo.class`
2. run it: `java Foo`  --> this takes `Foo.class` and executes it

I suggest you try to compile and run the program without the redirection first, then if that works, try to get the redirection working.

Comment: TicketSystem is the name of the program that contains multiple classes, how would I use `java` on a program with multiple classes?

Comment: When you say "program" I think you mean "directory". The program consists of the various source files inside the directory. You need to compile all source files, like `javac TicketSystem/*.java` - Then run (using `javac`) the one containing the `main` method. This is actually pretty basic usage - I suggest you read up on java in general first.

Comment: This was helpful, but now when I run my main class using `java TicketSystem/src/Main` (Main being my main class) I get a list of errors `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `(wrong name Main)` ... any thoughts as to why?

Comment: You can't just specify the class using the full path like you showed. Provided your `.class` files are in your current directory, you can probably just say `java Main`. If they are inside `TicketSystem/src` you can say `java -classpath TicketSystem/src Main`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
    echo "login" | java <class name that contains main method> > Output.txt
```

`javac` is the compile command which produces .class files.  For instance if I have Program.java that contains a `main` method, I would first run

```
    javac Program.java
```

Which would produce a Program.class file.  You would then run

```
    java Program
```

to execute the main method the program.

So in this case if your main method was in Program.java, you would run

```
    echo "login" | java Program > Output.txt
```